# Can I find a modulus of continuity in this case?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

Suppose that for a certain function $b \colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ I can show that there exists a local modulus of continuity $\omega_R$ and $C>0$ (both independent of $\epsilon$) such that
$$|b(x)-b(y)|\leq \frac{|x-y|}{\epsilon} \omega_R(|x-y|) $$
for every $\epsilon>0$.

Can I say then that
$$|b(x)-b(y)|\leq  \gamma_R \left (\frac{|x-y|^2}{\epsilon} \right ) $$
for some local modulus of continuity $\gamma_R$ (independent of $\epsilon$)?

Indeed if $\omega_R=C_R$ some constant depending of $R$ then this is true. In general I  would like to write $\epsilon=\sqrt \epsilon \sqrt \epsilon$ but then I cannot say that $\omega_R(|x-y|)/ \sqrt \epsilon \leq \omega_R(|x-y|/\epsilon)$. If this was true then I would have $\gamma_R$. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by local modulus of continuity and what is $R$? Does it mean that the inequality holds in $[-R,R]$? Don’t you get that the derivative is always zero?

Comment: By local modulus I mean that $\omega_R$ is a modulus of continuity on the closed ball of radius $R$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you divide by $|x-y|$ you get
$$
\left\vert \frac{b(x)-b(y)}{x-y}\right\vert \leq\frac{1}{\varepsilon}
\omega_{R}(|x-y|).
$$
Letting $y\rightarrow x$ you get
$$
0\leq\limsup_{y\rightarrow x}\left\vert \frac{b(x)-b(y)}{x-y}\right\vert
\leq\lim_{y\rightarrow x}\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\omega_{R}(|x-y|)=0
$$
since $\omega_{R}$ is a modulus of continuity. Hence,
$$
\lim_{y\rightarrow x}\left\vert \frac{b(x)-b(y)}{x-y}\right\vert =0,
$$
which implies that
$$
b^{\prime}(x)=\lim_{y\rightarrow x}\frac{b(x)-b(y)}{x-y}=0.
$$
Thus, $b^{\prime}(x)=0$ for every $x$, and so $b$ is a constant function.